# How to refactor this code to make it more readable and efficient?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I need help refactoring the code.I ve tried by best landed with the following code. Is there anything That I can do

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :get_cart
  before_action :set_credit_details, only: [:create]

  # process order
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    # Add items from cart to order's ordered_items association
    @cart.ordered_items.each do |item|
      @order.ordered_items << item
    end

    # Add shipping and tax to order total
    @order.total = case params[:order][:shipping_method]
    when 'ground'
      (@order.taxed_total).round(2)
    when 'two-day'
      @order.taxed_total + (15.75).round(2)
    when "overnight"
      @order.taxed_total + (25).round(2)
    end

    # Process credit card

    # Check if card is valid
    if @credit_card.valid?

    billing_address = { 
      name: "#{params[:billing_first_name]} # . 
      {params[:billing_last_name]}",
      address1: params[:billing_address_line_1],
      city: params[:billing_city], state: params[:billing_state],
      country: 'US',zip: params[:billing_zip],
      phone: params[:billing_phone]
     }
    options = { address: {}, billing_address: billing_address }

   # Make the purchase through ActiveMerchant
    charge_amount = (@order.total.to_f * 100).to_i
  response = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new(
      login: ENV["AUTHORIZE_LOGIN"],
      password: ENV["AUTHORIZE_PASSWORD"]
    ).purchase(charge_amount, @credit_card, options)

  unless response.success?
    @order.errors.add(:error, "We couldn't process your credit 
  card")
  end
else
  @order.errors.add(:error, "Your credit card seems to be invalid")
  flash[:error] = "There was a problem processing your order. Please try again."
  render :new && return
end

@order.order_status = 'processed'

if @order.save
  # get rid of cart
  Cart.destroy(session[:cart_id])
  # send order confirmation email
  OrderMailer.order_confirmation(order_params[:billing_email], session[:order_id]).deliver
  flash[:success] = "You successfully ordered!"
  redirect_to confirmation_orders_path
else
  flash[:error] = "There was a problem processing your order. Please try again."
  render :new
end
end

private

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit!
end

def get_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
end

def set_credit_details
  # Get credit card object from ActiveMerchant
  @credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
    number: params[:card_info][:card_number],
    month: params[:card_info][:card_expiration_month],
    year: params[:card_info][:card_expiration_year],
    verification_value: params[:card_info][:cvv],
    first_name: params[:card_info][:card_first_name],
    last_name: params[:card_info][:card_last_name],
    type: get_card_type # Get the card type
  )
end

def get_card_type
  length, number = params[:card_info][:card_number].size, params[:card_info][:card_number]
  case
  when length == 15 && number =~ /^(34|37)/
    "AMEX"
  when length == 16 && number =~ /^6011/
    "Discover"
  when length == 16 && number =~ /^5[1-5]/
    "MasterCard"
  when (length == 13 || length == 16) && number =~ /^4/
    "Visa"
  else
    "Unknown"
  end
end

end
```

Products with a price attribute. We have shopping Carts that have many Products through the OrderedItems join table. An OrderedItem belongs_to a Cart and a Product. It has a quantity attribute to keep track of the number of products ordered.

The OrderedItem also belongs_to an Order

I wanted to know if it can be refactored further.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to CodeReview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all you should move all that business logic from the controller into models and services (OrderProcessService, PaymentService). All the controller's private methods belong to a `PaymentService`.
2. Split the code into smaller methods.

   If doing that on the model level some things that come into my mind when reading your code are the following:

   `@order.add_items_from_cart(@cart)`

   `@order.add_shipping_and_tax(shipping_method)`
3. Orders should be first saved (persisted in DB), then processed (purchased with changing their status).

   - `@order.save` might fail after a successful payment, so a client will lose the money and not get their order.
   - the purchasing is an important and critical process, so you should make sure everything is ready for it (the order is valid and saved)
   - a client should be able to purchase later or after the payment page is accidentally reloaded without filling the form again
   - normally when a payment is performed you should send an order ID to the payment system. The payment system will store the ID and you will always know which order the payment belongs to.

There are a lot of other things to consider. You have a lot of work to do.

Comment: Orders should be first saved (persisted in DB), could you elaborate why this should happen